# Python multiprocessing edit-distance calculation

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bioinformatics

I have only been programming for about a year so know the basics very well but I'm struggling to get my head around the python multiprocessing documentation. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction for the problem at hand.

I am using the python-Levenshtein c-module to calculate the pair-wise distance between a large number of DNA sequences (~5000-2000) and would like to speed things up using multiprocessing. Pseudo-code for a basic version of my problem is below:

```
def edit_distance(seqA, seqB):
    ...
    return distance

sequence_list = [seq1, seq2, ... seq10000]
results_dict = {}    

centroid = sequence_list[0]
results_dict[centroid] = {}
for target in sequence_list[1:]:
    results_dict[centroid][target] = edit_distance(centroid, target)
```

When fully implemented this will be carried out using each seq as a centroid. It would be great if someone could point out which method would be best to multiprocess the calculation of distances for all targets in sequence_list[1:]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to get multiprocessing version of your code:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool

def dist_mp(centroid, target):
    return target, edit_distance(centroid, target)

def main():
    # ...
    pool = Pool() # use all CPUs
    for target, d in pool.imap_unordered(partial(dist_mp, centroid),
                                         sequence_list[1:]):
        results_dict[centroid][target] = d
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If `edit_distance()` function releases GIL then you could use threads instead of processes:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads
```

Note: you might get better time performance if you use an algorithm with better time complexity (avoid calling `edit_distance()` function `O(n**2)` times in "when fully implemented" case) instead of just improving it by a constant factor by using multiprocessing.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me but actually takes 10x longer than on a single process. I assume there may be quite a large overhead with creating new process which is causing the massive slow down? Re: time complexity, I have already implemented some time saving steps but I need the comparisons to be exhaustive so how far I can take this is limited.

Comment: @edm: all processes are created by `Pool()`. I doubt that the time difference is due to the creating of new processes unless `sequence_list` is small and `edit_distance()` takes negligible time (reuse the pool instead of creating a new one in this case). You could try to eliminate unnecessary `target` copying between the main process and workers (e.g., using `zip()` or passing `sequence_list` indices instead) and/or try different `chunksize` argument for `imap()`.